# Multiselect vba

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code for opening multiple files and then taking some actions on them. I  am only mentioning the part where i need help.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim i As Integer

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(myFile) Then 
    For i = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
    Set mywkbook= Workbooks.Open(myFile(i))
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

This works good.
But I want "mywkbook" variable to have different value for different workbook so that I can work on them.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work somewhat like this :

```
Dim paths(), wbs() As Workbook
Dim x As Integer

paths = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files 
(*.XLSX),*.XLSX", MultiSelect:=True)


  For x = 1 To UBound(paths)
  ReDim wbs(UBound(paths))
 Set wbs(x) = Workbooks.Open(paths(x))

   With wbs(x).Sheets("Sheet1")

  lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("A2:X" & lastrow).Copy newexcel.Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & 
newexcel.Sheets("RawData").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

 End With
 Next x
```

Posting my answer so that it can help someone in future :)

Answer (score 0):

One scalar variable cannot have different values at the same time, so you will have to use an array. You could do this by modifying your code like that:

```
Sub Sample()

  Dim myFile As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim mywkbooks() as Workbook

  myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

  If IsArray(myFile) Then 

    For i = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
    Set mywkbooks(i) = Workbooks.Open(myFile(i))
    Next i

  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this comes through ok, this is my first Answer on this forum.

```
Sub tryThis()

Dim myFile As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim workbookNames() As String ' define a empty string array variable to hold the file names

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(myFile) Then
    For i = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
        Workbooks.Open (myFile(i))   ' Just open the workbook here
        ReDim Preserve workbookNames(i) ' ReDim redefines your array to 'i' number of elements.  Preserve ensures you don't lose the previous values held in the Array
        workbookNames(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Name ' Assign the Name of the Workbook to the Array
            MsgBox workbookNames(i) ' you don't need this, I just used it to demonstrate that you now have the file name and can work with it
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Edit: I was tying this at the same time as 'Binarus'.  I like their approach of declaring a Workbook Array but you will need to add the following line before 'Set mywkbooks(i)' otherwise you will get a Subscript out of range error as the Array is empty and cannot hold any values yet.

ReDim Preserve mywkbooks(i)